# Convergence for all $\theta$ of a sum with periodic function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fourier-series

How can I show that:

$$
\sum_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{\sin(n\theta)}{n}
$$

converges for all $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: By [Summation by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts)

Answer (score 2):

If $\theta\in\pi\mathbb{Z}$ the series yields obviously zero, while assuming $\theta\not\in\pi\mathbb{Z}$ we have $\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\neq 0$ and:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sin(n\theta) = \frac{\sin\left(\frac{N}{2}\theta\right)\sin\left(\frac{N+1}{2}\theta\right)}{\sin\frac{\theta}{2}},$$
so by setting $S_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sin(n\theta)$ we have: 
$$|S_N|\leq\frac{1}{|\sin(\theta/2)|}=K.\tag{1}$$

Now we apply summation by parts:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{M}\frac{\sin n\theta}{n}=\frac{S_M}{M}+\sum_{n=1}^{M-1}\frac{S_n}{n(n+1)}\tag{2}.$$

Since the absolute value of any $S_j$ is bounded by $K$ by $(1)$, the last identity gives that the original series is a convergent one, converging towards:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{S_n}{n(n+1)}$$
whose absolute value is less than $K$. There is also a general criterion: if $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence with bounded partial sums and $\{b_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an increasing sequence diverging to $+\infty$, the series:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{a_n}{b_n}$$
converges. The proof goes along the same lines.

The continuous analogue is the following: if $f,g$ are two Riemann-integrable functions over $\mathbb{R}^+$, $g\in C^{0}(\mathbb{R}^+)$ is a non-increasing function and $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt$ is bounded for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$, then $f\cdot g$ is a Riemann-integrable function over $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Sometimes, both criteria are known as "the Dirichlet criterion".

Another possible approach is to notice that your series is just the Fourier series of the sawtooth wave, yielding:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{n}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\pi\left\{\frac{x}{2\pi}\right\}\tag{3}$$
for any $\theta\not\in\pi\mathbb{Z}$, where $\{y\}=y-\lfloor y\rfloor$.

Comment: Is not $(b_n)_n$  increasing ?

Comment: An increasing but bounded $b_n$ would not ensure the convergence of the series, take $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin n}{1-e^{-n}},$$ for instance.

Comment: This is not the only property for $b_n$, but a supplementary property for the convergence.

Comment: Ah, ok. Now I understand what you are meaning. Yes, you are right, I am updating my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Set 
$$
s_n(\vartheta)=\sin\vartheta+\sin(2\vartheta)+\cdots+\sin(n\vartheta)=\mathrm{Re}\left(\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta}+\cdots+\mathrm{e}^{in\vartheta}\right)=\cdots=\frac{\sin(n\vartheta/2) \sin[(n+1)\vartheta/2]}{\sin(\vartheta/2)} 
$$
and $s_n(0)=0$. Hence $s_n(\vartheta)$ is bounded for every $\vartheta$, say by $M(\vartheta)$. Then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sin (k\vartheta)}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{s_{k}(\vartheta)-s_{k-1}(\vartheta)}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{s_{k}(\vartheta)}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{s_{k-1}(\vartheta)}{k} \\ =\frac{s_n(\vartheta)}{n}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{s_{k}(\vartheta)}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{s_{k}(\vartheta)}{k+1}=\frac{\sin(n\vartheta/2) \sin[(n+1)\vartheta/2]}{n\sin(\vartheta/2)} +\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{s_{k}(\vartheta)}{k(k+1)}.
$$
Now the first term $\frac{\sin(n\vartheta/2) \sin[(n+1)\vartheta/2]}{n\sin(\vartheta/2)}$ tends to zero, for every $\vartheta$, while the second term  $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{s_{k}(\vartheta)}{k(k+1)}$ is bounded by
$$
M(\vartheta)\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k(k+1)},
$$
which establishes summability (conditional of course) of our series.